# Runtime Error : NZEC

Tags: java, runtime-error

I keep getting a runtime error on my submission to the problem at http://www.codechef.com/problems/LASTDIG.

My code is as follows :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int i,j;
            System.out.println("Enter the no. of test cases - ");
            int cases = in.nextInt();

            int[][] a = new int[cases][2];
            int[] lds = new int[cases]; 

            for(i=0; i<cases; i++) {
                for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
                    a[i][j]=in.nextInt();
                }
            }

            for(j=0; j<cases; j++) {
                lds[j] = 0;
                int LENGTH = a[j][1] - a[j][0] +1;
                int[] arr = new int[LENGTH];
                //System.out.printf("%d\n",LENGTH);
                int[]sum = new int[LENGTH];

                for(i=0; i<LENGTH; i++) {
                    sum[i] = 0;
                    arr[i] = a[j][0] + i;
                }

                for(i=0; i<LENGTH; i++) {
                    int temp = arr[i];
                    while(temp !=0 ) {
                        int r = temp%10;
                        temp /= 10;

                        if (r%2 == 0) sum[i] += r*2;
                        else sum[i] += r;
                    }
                }

                for(i=0; i<LENGTH; i++){
                    lds[j] += sum[i]%10;
                }

            }

            for(i=0; i<cases; i++) {
                System.out.printf("%d\n",lds[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me out over here, considering the problem is an easy one.

Thanks !

Comment: Also, you should consider reducing your code sample to only what's necessary to trigger the error.

Comment: The error is ent via e-mail, so all I know is that it is caused due to some unhandled exception.

Comment: I tried to place the try, catch blocks elsewhere, but still the error persists, hence I had to post this here !

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from actually running your code over sample input yourself to see whether and where it breaks.

Comment: Ya, I did that too. Surprisingly, all my test cases work just fine ! :D

Answer (score 0):

The code itself runs fine ... given that sensible input is given.  For different input, errors could occur like:

1. What if the cases is not an integer?
2. What if the cases is a negative integer?

So, as the edits try to accomplish, we need to give sensible feedback for unforeseen use cases.

But for the problem in the link, there are other potential issues.  Overflow?  Overflow will not exist for really large numbers, 2^32 is greater than the largest number, but I do notice that a large integer can give an OutOfMemory error, so I reckon this bit of code comes down to inefficiency and the need for a better algorithm to handle larger integers.